# Slurm: Error when submitting to multiple nodes ("slurmstepd: error: execve(): python: No such file or directory")

Tags: bash, distributed-computing, slurm, sbatch

I have have a bash script `submit.sh` for submitting training jobs to a Slurm server. It works as follows. Doing

```
bash submit.sh p1 8 config_file
```

will submit some task corresponding to `config_file` to 8 GPUs of partition `p1`. Each node of `p1` has 4 GPUs, thus this command requests 2 nodes.

The content of `submit.sh` can be summarized as follows, in which I use `sbatch` to submit a Slurm script (`train.slurm`):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# submit.sh

PARTITION=$1
NGPUs=$2
CONFIG=$3

NGPUS_PER_NODE=4
NCPUS_PER_TASK=10

sbatch --partition ${PARTITION} \
    --job-name=${CONFIG} \
    --output=logs/${CONFIG}_%j.log \
    --ntasks=${NGPUs} \
    --ntasks-per-node=${NGPUS_PER_NODE} \
    --cpus-per-task=${NCPUS_PER_TASK} \
    --gres=gpu:${NGPUS_PER_NODE} \
    --hint=nomultithread \
    --time=10:00:00
    --export=CONFIG=${CONFIG},NGPUs=${NGPUs},NGPUS_PER_NODE=${NGPUS_PER_NODE} \
    train.slurm
```

Now in the Slurm script, `train.slurm`, I decide whether to launch the training Python script on one or multiple nodes (the ways to launch it are different in these two cases):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# train.slurm
#SBATCH --distribution=block:block

# Load Python environment
module purge
module load pytorch/py3/1.6.0
 
set -x

if [ ${NGPUs} -gt ${NGPUS_PER_NODE} ]; then # Multi-node training
    # Some variables needed for the training script
    export MASTER_PORT=12340
    export WORLD_SIZE=${NGPUs}
    # etc.

    srun python train.py --cfg ${CONFIG}
else # Single-node training
    python -u -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=${NGPUS_PER_NODE} --use_env train.py --cfg ${CONFIG}
fi
```

Now if I submit on a single node (e.g., `bash submit.sh p1 4 config_file`), it works as expected. However, submitting on multiple nodes (e.g., `bash submit.sh p1 8 config_file`) produced the following error:

```
slurmstepd: error: execve(): python: No such file or directory
```

This means that the Python environment was not recognized on one of the nodes. I tried replacing `python` with `$(which python)` to take the full path to the Python binary in the virtual environment, but then I obtained another error:

```
OSError: libmpi_cxx.so.40: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I don't use `submit.sh` but instead, add all the `#SBATCH` variable to `train.slurm`, and submit the job using `sbatch` directly from the command line, then it works. Therefore, it seems that **wrapping `sbatch` inside a bash script caused this issue**.

Could you please help me to resolve this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Beware that the `--export` parameter will cause the environment for `srun` to be reset to exactly all the `SLURM_*` variables plus the ones explicitly set, so in your case `CONFIG`,`NGPUs`, `NGPUS_PER_NODE`. Consequently, the `PATH` variable will not be set and `srun` will not find the `python` executable.

Note that the `--export` does not alter the environment of the submission script, so the single-node case, that does not use `srun`, does indeed run fine.

Try submitting with

```
--export=ALL,CONFIG=${CONFIG},NGPUs=${NGPUs},NGPUS_PER_NODE=${NGPUS_PER_NODE} \
```

Note the added `ALL` as first item in the list.

Another option is to simply remove the `--export` line entirely and export the variables explicitly in the `submit.sh` script as the submission environment is propagated by default by Slurm to the job.

```
export PARTITION=$1
export NGPUs=$2
export CONFIG=$3

export NGPUS_PER_NODE=4
export NCPUS_PER_TASK=10
```